# jQuery jump to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I've something like an image gallery on my site. By clicking an image this one will scale up. Sometimes the enlargement contains that a part of the image is out of the viewport. Is it possible that the complete site jumps to the top area of the image by clicking it?

You can have a look [here](http://relaunch.headonline.de/projekte/campus-symposium-eventkommunikation/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div.image img").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

It should create a click event for all the images inside the div element with a class "image", which I can see in your code, and then animate (slowly, in 2000 miliseconds, aka 2 seconds) scroll to it's offset from the top of the page.

You have more information in this [5 year old question on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

edit:
if you need some adjustment, you can edit this line

```
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 88
```

and the page will scroll 88px less than the image position, which you could find helpful because of your floating menu.